# Is it possible to upload an image to Firebase from Laravel 5 project? How?

Tags: firebase, laravel-5, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to develop website using Laravel 5 framework and Firebase Database. I need to upload images, videos, and audios to the database through Laravel.

Is it possible to do such things in Laravel? If so, how do I do such things using Laravel?

Comment: I am sure that it is possible. This is going to be closed until you add some code that we (as community) can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync

https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php

https://github.com/eelkevdbos/firebase-php

As a heads up--none of these are officially supported by the Firebase team.